# Creating and saving new tr elements with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I’m fairly new to coding, especially JS. I’m building a program meant to calculate input and put the result (along with the date) into a table. There should be a new entry in the table every time there is new input. Whenever the page is reloaded, the table’s data should be saved and retrieved.

The problem I’m having now is that only the first entry is saved. All the data in the table must be saved. Does anybody have a suggestion? Thanks.

Here's my code:

```js
// variables

const input = document.getElementById('input');

//buttons

const enter = document.getElementById('enter-value');
const log = document.getElementById("log-value");
const save = document.getElementById("save-value");
const done = document.getElementById("done-button");

//log areas

const itemHolder = document.getElementById('item-holder');
const totalMarker = document.getElementById("grand-total");

// messagges

const negativeValueMessage = document.getElementById('value-message-negative');
const positiveValueMessage = document.getElementById('value-message-positive');
const doneMessage = document.getElementById('done');

//other

const tool = document.getElementById('tool');
const date = new Date();

//input testing code

function checkInput (){
    input.addEventListener('input', function(){
        if(input.value < 0 ){
           negativeValueMessage.style.display = "block";
           positiveValueMessage.style.display = "none";
           enter.style.display = "block";
           enter.disabled = false;
           enter.style.opacity = "100%";
        }
        else if (input.value > 0) {
            negativeValueMessage.style.display = "none";
            positiveValueMessage.style.display = "block";
            enter.style.display = "block";
            enter.disabled = false;
            enter.style.opacity = "100%";
        }
        else {
            negativeValueMessage.style.display = "none";
            positiveValueMessage.style.display = "none";
            enter.disabled = true;
            if(enter.disabled){
                enter.style.opacity = '60%';
            }
        }
    });
}
checkInput();

// input reception

function useInput (){
    enter.addEventListener('click', function(){
        enter.style.display = 'none';
        log.style.display = 'block';
        inputDisalowed();
        log.addEventListener('click', function(){
            const addValues = Number(input.value) + Number(totalMarker.value);
            const total = addValues;
            totalMarker.value = total;
            function newInfo(){
                itemHolder.innerHTML += '<tr><td id="date">' + dateHolder + '</td><td id="amount">$' + totalMarker.value + '</td></tr>';
            }
            newInfo();
            log.style.display = 'none';
            save.style.display = 'block';
            save.addEventListener('click', function(){
                doneMessage.style.display = "grid";
                tool.style.display = 'none';
                const dateData = document.getElementById('date').innerText;
                const amountData = document.getElementById('amount').innerText;
                const dataArray = [dateData, amountData];
                localStorage.setItem('savedDate', (dataArray[0]));
                localStorage.setItem('savedAmount', dataArray[1]);
                localStorage.setItem('savedTotal', Number(totalMarker.value));
                done.addEventListener('click', function(){
                    reloadPage();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
useInput();
retrieveOnReload();
const dateHolder = monthFixedValue() + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();

function monthFixedValue (){
    return date.getMonth() + 1;
}
function inputDisalowed (){
    input.addEventListener('input', function(){
        alert("You have already input your value. Inputing again will always restart the proccess.");
        location.reload();
    });
}
function retrieveOnReload(){
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    const retrievedDate = localStorage.getItem('savedDate');
    const retrieveAmount = localStorage.getItem('savedAmount');
    itemHolder.innerHTML += '<tr><td id="date">' + retrievedDate + '</td><td id="amount">' + retrieveAmount + '</td></tr>';});
    totalMarker.value = Number(localStorage.getItem('savedTotal'));
};
function reloadPage() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
}
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width:13px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background: rgb(160,180,190);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: rgb(120,140,150);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
body {
    background-image: url(/Background.svg);
    display: grid;
    width: 100vw;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    background-position: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
}
h1{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        rgb(150,170,180),
        rgb(120,140,150)
    );
    border-radius: .5vw;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 70px;
    min-width: 400px;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(20,20,90);
    font-size: 40px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
main{
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
    background: linear-gradient(
        rgb(150,170,180) 20%,
        rgb(120,140,150) 
    );
    border-radius: .5vw;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 80vw;
    min-width: 400px;;
}
.inputs {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
input {
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(30,90,130);
    color: rgb(10,10,50);
    height: 35px;
    width: 220px;
    font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(20,80,100);
    border-radius: .2vw;
    margin-right: 3px;
    &::placeholder{
        color: rgb(100,140,180);
        font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 900;
    }
}
#enter-value, #save-value, #log-value{
    border: none;
    border-radius: .2vw;
    background: rgb(20,80,180);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: rgb(10,10,50);
    margin-left: 3px;
    &:hover{
        background: rgb(10,70,170);
    }
    &:active{
        background: rgb(20,80,180);
    }
}
#enter-value{
    display: none;
}
#save-value{
    display: none;
}
#log-value{
    display: none;
}
.value-message{
    color: rgb(30,40,100);
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}
label{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    display: flex;
    align-items: baseline;
    font-size: 35px;
    
}
#grand-total{
    height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: rgb(10,10,100);
    color: rgb(150,170,180);
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.table-window{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
table{
    background-color: rgb(60,120,160);
    border-style: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.heading-row{
    background: rgb(100,160,200);
    height: 40px;
    width: 750px;
}
th{
    border: 0;
    width: 170px;
}
td{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 170px;
}
.th1,
.th2,
.th3{
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(170,170,255);
}
.td1,
.td2,
.td3{
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(170,170,255);
}
#done{
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    display: none;
}
#done-img-holder{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#done-img-holder > img{
    width: 490px;
    display: grid;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
#done-info-holder{
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 170px;
    background: linear-gradient(
        rgb(180,180,190),
        rgb(140,140,150)
    );
    align-content: center;
    border-radius: .5vw;
}
#done-info-holder > p{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgb(10,70,160);
    font-weight: 900;
}
#done-info-holder > button{
    height: 50px;
    width: 130px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 900;
    background: rgb(10,10,100);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: rgb(120,140,150);
    &:hover{
        background: rgb(120,140,150);
        color: rgb(10,10,100);
    }
    &:active{
        background: rgb(10,10,100);
        color: rgb(120,140,150);
    }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="veiwport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FinanceTool.css">
    <title>Finance_Tool</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main id="tool">
            <h1 class="heading">Simple Finance Tool</h1>
        <p id="value-message-negative" class="value-message">Your number is negative. This will be calculated as a financial loss.</p>
        <p id="value-message-positive" class="value-message">Your number is positive. This will be calculated as a financial gain.</p>
        <div class="inputs">
            <input type='number' id="input" class="input" placeholder="Input financial loss or gain." min="0"/>
            <button type="button" id="enter-value">Enter</button>
            <button type="button" id="log-value">Log Change</button>
            <button type="button" id="save-value">Save Change</button>
        </div>
        <label for="grand-total">$<input id="grand-total" disabled/></label>
        <div class="table-window">
            <table id="item-holder">
                <tr class="heading-row">
                    <th class="th1">Date</th>
                    <th class="th4">Total After Change</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            
            
        </div>
        
    </main>
    <div id="done">
        <div id="done-img-holder">
            <img src="/Finance Tool/check-circle-svgrepo-com.svg"/>
        </div>
        <div id="done-info-holder">
            <p>All done! You're entry is complete.</p>
            <button id="done-button">Done</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="FinanceTool.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also here’s a link to the code in codePen(note: due to a peculiarity of codePen, the code will not work properly in it, but you can copy it from codePen to your IDE).

[codePenProjectLink](https://codepen.io/Front-End-Learner/pen/ExJPdPQ?editors=0010)

Comment: if you need to store the entries you can do that by storing it into an array ex using array.push(). you can then retrieve the stored data

Comment: Thanks @Mehdi. Will you fill that out though?

Comment: FWIW your CSS and style/colors make this nearly unreadable when rendered.

Comment: I don't get it. You mean the page content can't be read?

Comment: Dark text on a dark background is difficult to read.

Comment: Thanks @mykaf . I will look into changing it, but not until I receive an answer to my JS question. I think it is still readable, though no doubt it could be improved.

Comment: So, upon page load, read your value(s) from localStorage. Add it to that value as needed, then re-save to localStorage.

Comment: Thankyou for your effort @mykaf, but that doesn't work.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Please update your question to show your attempt with this.

Comment: You don't seem to "add to the value as needed"; you seem to be only setting the most recent values to localStorage, rather than adding to the history.

Comment: Many things need to be changed in your code. As also @Mark Schultheiss suggested you need to change your colors as it is almost unreadable. As per saving your data into array you can add for example this right after your   'date' and amount 'id' are in the DOM

Comment: let dateData = document.getElementById('date').innerText;
                let amountData = document.getElementById('amount').innerText;
                dateArray.push(dateData)
                amountArray.push(amountData)
                localStorage.setItem('savedDate', JSON.stringify(dateArray));
                localStorage.setItem('savedAmount', JSON.stringify(amountArray));

Comment: and then to retrieve your data you can add this loop in your DOMContentLoaded listener :          for(let i=0; i < dateArray.length ; i++){
            let retrievedDate = localStorage.getItem('dateArray');
            retrievedDate = JSON.parse(retrievedDate)
            let retrieveAmount = localStorage.getItem('amountArray');
            retrieveAmount = JSON.parse(retrieveAmount)

            itemHolder.innerHTML += '<tr><td id="date">' + retrievedDate[i] + '</td><td id="amount">' + retrieveAmount[i] + '</td></tr>';  
        }.

Comment: But you really need first to improve your code and I am sure you can as far as I can see what you have already written 

Comment: You can check your arrays in your localstorage in your devtools Application section

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a new as can be. Your last comment was baffling because of my lack of understanding. Could you elaborate? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You need also to déclaré on top of your JS file dateArray=[ ] and amountArray=[ ]. You Can also use array of objets to put date and and amount values together

Comment: So, you mean I need to create two new arrays??? If so, how are you expecting me to use them?

Comment: @BenLeevey yes 2 arrays or one array of object(each object will containe 2 values {amount and date} )for example try to update your code that way and tomorrow I will try to have a closer look if I can help

Comment: @Mehdi This would be much better posted as an answer instead of split into multiple comments that lack indentation and syntax highlighting.

Comment: You are right @sean will write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a starter for you to see how we can proceed if I properly understood your needs. I made 2 type of array, simple array (dateArray and amountArray) and dailyInputArray = array of object(dailyInput ). Also note that for a better and safer storage you need to store in MySQL database. NB I think because of using localstorage the code snippet does not seem to work on SO pls check it in your code editor.

```js
let amountArray=[]
let dateArray=[]
let dailyInput={}
let dailyInputArray=[]
let retrieveDailyInputValues = localStorage.getItem('DailyInputValues');
retrieveDailyInputValues = JSON.parse(retrieveDailyInputValues)
console.log(retrieveDailyInputValues)
if(retrieveDailyInputValues && retrieveDailyInputValues.length!=0){
    dailyInputArray=retrieveDailyInputValues
}else{
    dailyInputArray=[]
}


const input = document.getElementById('input');

//buttons

const enter = document.getElementById('enter-value');
const log = document.getElementById("log-value");
const save = document.getElementById("save-value");
const done = document.getElementById("done-button");

//log areas

const itemHolder = document.getElementById('item-holder');
const earningHolder = document.getElementById('earning-holder');
const totalMarker = document.getElementById("grand-total");

// messagges

const negativeValueMessage = document.getElementById('value-message-negative');
const positiveValueMessage = document.getElementById('value-message-positive');
const doneMessage = document.getElementById('done');

//other

const tool = document.getElementById('tool');
const date = new Date();
const dateHolder = monthFixedValue() + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
function monthFixedValue (){
    return date.getMonth() + 1;
}


//input testing code

function checkInput (){
    input.addEventListener('input', function(){
        if(input.value < 0 ){
           negativeValueMessage.style.display = "block";
           positiveValueMessage.style.display = "none";
           enter.style.display = "block";
           enter.disabled = false;
           enter.style.opacity = "100%";
        }
        else if (input.value > 0) {
            negativeValueMessage.style.display = "none";
            positiveValueMessage.style.display = "block";
            enter.style.display = "block";
            enter.disabled = false;
            enter.style.opacity = "100%";
        }
        else {
            negativeValueMessage.style.display = "none";
            positiveValueMessage.style.display = "none";
            enter.disabled = true;
            if(enter.disabled){
                enter.style.opacity = '60%';
            }
        }
    });
}
checkInput();

// input reception

function useInput (){
    enter.addEventListener('click', function(){
        enter.style.display = 'none';
        log.style.display = 'block';
        inputDisalowed();
        log.addEventListener('click', function(){
            dailyInput.date = dateHolder
            dailyInput.earnings = input.value
            dailyInputArray.push(dailyInput)
            console.log(dailyInput)
            console.log(dailyInputArray)
            localStorage.setItem('DailyInputValues', JSON.stringify(dailyInputArray)); 
            const addValues = Number(input.value) + Number(totalMarker.value);
            const total = addValues;
            totalMarker.value = total;
            function newInfo(){
                itemHolder.innerHTML += '<tr><td id="date">' + dateHolder + '</td><td id="amount">$' + totalMarker.value + '</td></tr>';
            }
            newInfo();
            log.style.display = 'none';
            save.style.display = 'block';
            save.addEventListener('click', function(){
                doneMessage.style.display = "grid";
                tool.style.display = 'none';
                let dateData = document.getElementById('date').innerText; 
                let amountData = document.getElementById('amount').innerText; 
                dateArray.push(dateData) 
                amountArray.push(amountData) 
                localStorage.setItem('savedDate', JSON.stringify(dateArray)); 
                localStorage.setItem('savedAmount', JSON.stringify(amountArray)); 
                // const dataArray = [dateData, amountData];
                // localStorage.setItem('savedDate', (dataArray[0]));
                // localStorage.setItem('savedAmount', dataArray[1]);
                localStorage.setItem('savedTotal', Number(totalMarker.value));
                // done.addEventListener('click', function(){
                //     reloadPage();
                // });
            });
        });
    });
}
useInput();
retrieveOnReload();

function inputDisalowed (){
    input.addEventListener('input', function(){
        alert("You have already input your value. Inputing again will always restart the proccess.");
        // location.reload();
    });
}
function retrieveOnReload(){
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        for(let i=0; i < dateArray.length ; i++){ 
            let retrievedDate = localStorage.getItem('dateArray'); 
            retrievedDate = JSON.parse(retrievedDate) 
            let retrieveAmount = localStorage.getItem('amountArray'); 
            retrieveAmount = JSON.parse(retrieveAmount)
            itemHolder.innerHTML += '<tr><td class="date">' + retrievedDate[i] + '</td><td class="amount">' + retrieveAmount[i] + '</td></tr>';
         }

         for(let j=0; j < retrieveDailyInputValues.length ; j++){ 
            let retrieveEarningdDate = dailyInputArray[j].date 
            let retrieveDailyEarning = dailyInputArray[j].earnings 
            earningHolder.innerHTML += '<tr><td class="date">' + retrieveEarningdDate + '</td><td class="amount">' + retrieveDailyEarning + '</td></tr>';
         }
    // const retrievedDate = localStorage.getItem('savedDate');
    // const retrieveAmount = localStorage.getItem('savedAmount');
    // itemHolder.innerHTML += '<tr><td id="date">' + retrievedDate + '</td><td id="amount">' + retrieveAmount + '</td></tr>';
});
    totalMarker.value = Number(localStorage.getItem('savedTotal'));
};
// function reloadPage() {
//     window.location.href = window.location.href;
// }
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width:13px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
  background: rgb(160,180,190);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  background: rgb(120,140,150);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
body {
  background-image: url(/Background.svg);
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  background-position: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
}
h1{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgb(150,170,180),
      rgb(120,140,150)
  );
  border-radius: .5vw;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 70px;
  min-width: 400px;
  font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: rgb(20,20,90);
  font-size: 40px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
main{
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(
      rgb(150,170,180) 20%,
      rgb(120,140,150) 
  );
  border-radius: .5vw;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80vw;
  min-width: 400px;;
}
.inputs {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
input {
  border: none;
  background-color: rgb(30,90,130);
  color: rgb(10,10,50);
  height: 35px;
  width: 220px;
  font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(20,80,100);
  border-radius: .2vw;
  margin-right: 3px;
  &::placeholder{
      color: rgb(100,140,180);
      font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 900;
  }
}
#enter-value, #save-value, #log-value{
  border: none;
  border-radius: .2vw;
  background: rgb(20,80,180);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: rgb(10,10,50);
  margin-left: 3px;
  &:hover{
      background: rgb(10,70,170);
  }
  &:active{
      background: rgb(20,80,180);
  }
}
#enter-value{
  display: none;
}
#save-value{
  display: none;
}
#log-value{
  display: none;
}
.value-message{
  color: rgb(30,40,100);
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
label{
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  font-size: 35px;
  
}
#grand-total{
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background: rgb(10,10,100);
  color: rgb(150,170,180);
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 35px;
}
.table-window{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
table{
  background-color: rgb(60,120,160);
  border-style: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.heading-row{
  background: rgb(100,160,200);
  height: 40px;
  width: 750px;
}
th{
  border: 0;
  width: 170px;
}
td{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 170px;
}
.th1,
.th2,
.th3{
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(170,170,255);
}
.td1,
.td2,
.td3{
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(170,170,255);
}
#done{
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  display: none;
}
#done-img-holder{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#done-img-holder > img{
  width: 490px;
  display: grid;
  margin-top: -30px;
}
#done-info-holder{
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  width: 400px;
  height: 170px;
  background: linear-gradient(
      rgb(180,180,190),
      rgb(140,140,150)
  );
  align-content: center;
  border-radius: .5vw;
}
#done-info-holder > p{
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(10,70,160);
  font-weight: 900;
}
#done-info-holder > button{
  height: 50px;
  width: 130px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  background: rgb(10,10,100);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  color: rgb(120,140,150);
  &:hover{
      background: rgb(120,140,150);
      color: rgb(10,10,100);
  }
  &:active{
      background: rgb(10,10,100);
      color: rgb(120,140,150);
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="veiwport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FinanceTool.css">
    <title>Finance_Tool</title>
</head>
<body>
<main id="tool">
    <h1 class="heading">Simple Finance Tool</h1>
<p id="value-message-negative" class="value-message">Your number is negative. This will be calculated as a financial loss.</p>
<p id="value-message-positive" class="value-message">Your number is positive. This will be calculated as a financial gain.</p>
<div class="inputs">
    <input type='number' id="input" class="input" placeholder="Input financial loss or gain." min="0"/>
    <button type="button" id="enter-value">Enter</button>
    <button type="button" id="log-value">Log Change</button>
    <button type="button" id="save-value">Save Change</button>
</div>
<label for="grand-total">$<input id="grand-total" disabled/></label>
<div class="table-window">
    <table id="item-holder">
        <tr class="heading-row">
            <th class="th1">Date</th>
            <th class="th4">Total After Change</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="earning-holder">
      <tr class="heading-row">
          <th class="th1">Date</th>
          <th class="th4">Earning</th>
      </tr>
  </table>
    
</div>

</main>
<div id="done">
<div id="done-img-holder">
    <img src="/Finance Tool/check-circle-svgrepo-com.svg"/>
</div>
<div id="done-info-holder">
    <p>All done! You're entry is complete.</p>
    <button id="done-button">Done</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This produces invalid HTML

Comment: @Mark may I know how pls?

Comment: `'<tr><td id="date">'`  Duplicate ID is invalid in HTML they must be unique in the entire DOM.

Comment: @Mark you are absolutely correct have not seen that! Needs to be corrected! Same thing for amount

Comment: @Mark really thanks for correcting me, should have seen that by myself I just replaced it using here a class when displaying table rows with date, the first id date is not repeated so I kept it. Happy coding